# How to react when one of my bosses belittles my authority in presence of my reports?

Tags: professionalism, management, communication, politics

All my seniors discuss with me first and thereafter leave it to me to handle all the workflow with the team.

One of my new bosses - who is not responsible for my overall performance BUT whom I report to on a defined set of responsibilities - talks to the whole team instead of checking with me first (both in person and via e-mail, i.e. he e-mails all at once rather than CC'ing them) - as if we are all on the same level of rank. On the one hand, I feel this belittles my authority in front of my reports, and on the other hand this shows little consideration towards our other workflows and deadlines, i.e. he asks us to do things without even knowing what other deadlines and projects we have.

What can I do to make sure that, in the first place, he doesn't address the whole team and instead talks to me first - both for the sake of my authority, and for the sake of proper coordination?

Comment: Hi WaterBrick and welcome to [The Workplace](workplace.stackexchange.com)! Unfortunately your question is almost identical to [How to build dialogue and cooperation when other managers bypass my authority as a manager?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/31514/19612) and is likely to get closed as a duplicate. If that question does not fully address your situation, please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/31667/edit) your question to highlight the differences. I hope to see you around! :)

Comment: I edited it to make the authority structure clearer - that question seems to address peer level managers, whereas mine is about one of my bosses.

Comment: Also, the other question seems to talk about peer managers who go behind a manager and give tasks to the reports - not throw them all in the same box.

Comment: Your first concern doesn't seem to be particularly valid.  Perhaps your organization is trying to flatten itself out a bit due to the benefits that can have on morale and productivity?  If so, you're not _meant_ to be seen as an authority figure and the boss's behavior is correct.  But only insofar as it does not subvert the development efforts.  The boss is responsible for understanding the schedule and project-management issues if he wants to engage with the team directly.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that this is not your direct boss, but a peer to your boss.  Before going to the peer to discuss this, I would take it to your boss first.  Explain to your boss that his peer is sending out emails with direction without being aware of the current process and projects, and it's confusing your direct reports.

Mention to your boss that you are doing your best to ensure the right items are worked on in the right priority, and that you think the confusion could be solved if his/her peer could come to you directly first before sending out the email to you and your team with direction.

Talking directly to your boss' peer isn't the best step until you have exhausted options with your direct boss.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear; this is not my boss' peer, but rather one of my bosses - though not my line manager in terms of performance reviews etc. He is however in charge of me in certain areas.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your line manager first.

Emphasize that this individual is by-passing you is at the cost of your ability to coordinate the team and live up to any previously given guarantees about meeting deadlines and milestones, and that's no good.

You should try communicating your concern directly to this individual since he is your boss on certain tasks. Make the concern as clear and the corrective steps that the individual as explicit and concise as possible. You want to tell this individual exactly what he is to do or not to do so that he does not get in your way. You want to be  just as corteous as you are firm.

If you don't get an adequate, suitably aggressive response from your line manager and you don't get an appropriate response from this individual in reasonably short order, escalate to your line manager's boss.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear; this is not my boss' peer, but one of my bosses - though not my line manager in terms of performance reviews etc. He still is in charge of me in certain areas.

Comment: @WaterBrick I have edited my answer in response to your clarification.